# Digest loop in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it safe to assume that the digest loop will run everytime I do something in the application? It's not the kind of a loop that runs constantly AFAIK, so there's a threat it will not execute when I want it to.

If I have an `ng-if` in html checking a boolean value that's in a service. I need to explicitly create a `$watch`, right? That `ng-if` will hide or show some text.

I want to make sure that if the value is `false`, then the text will become hidden.

Comment: use $scope in a controller, without async nativ things, then its save.

Comment: you can use $scope.$apply() to force the digest loop to run.

Comment: Do you check a boolean value from a service or in a $scope property? The digest loop only effects the $scope

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any $watch there.

You have some html code with ngIf directive on it. There is some model, assigned to this directive. Also, assume you have button which call function that reverts model. This function will be `click` handler for your button. You will have something like `ng-click='myFoo();`. When you click on button, ngClick directive will fire $digest loop by itself.

So, if you want to manipulate DOM you have to call $digest. Common directives, like ngClick, call $digest by themselves. If you use your own directive or some directive, which doesn't call $digest, you have to call it by yourself.

To call digest by yourself, you can use `$timeout` service or `$scope.$apply`, for example.

```
$scope.$apply(function () { $scope.someModel = true; });
```

Code of function will be fired and $apply will start $digest loop